# terraform "read during apply" message appearing with provider upgrade

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

When I upgrade my terraform azurerm provider from version 2.71.0 to version 2.88.0, I get extra plan output that I didn't have before. Namely this (x's are mine to obscure private information):

```
# module.xxxx.data.azurerm_app_service_environment.xxxx will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "azurerm_app_service_environment" "xxxx"  {
      ~ cluster_setting        = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ front_end_scale_factor = 5 -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                     = "xxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ internal_ip_address    = "xxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ location               = "xxxx" -> (known after apply)
        name                   = "xxxxxx"
      ~ outbound_ip_addresses  = [
          - "xxxxx",
        ] -> (known after apply)
      ~ pricing_tier           = "I2" -> (known after apply)
      ~ service_ip_address     = "xxxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ tags                   = {
         xxxxxx
        } -> (known after apply)
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)

      + timeouts {
          + read = (known after apply)
        }
```

Why is an update of provider version causing a change in plan output like this? I do not see any enhancements to azurerm_app_service_environment in the azurerm change logs.

What is the potential impact of this new output when I deploy?

Another new piece of output that I get from the same upgrade is this:

```
  ~ resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "xxxxxx" {
        id                  = "/subscriptions/xxxxxx"
        name                = "xxxxx"
      ~ records             = [
          - "xxxx",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        tags                = {}
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

The records entry is populated by data.azurerm_app_service_environment.xxx.internal_ip_address  so it is related to that first bit of new output. That internal_ip_address value has not changed. And none of this output appears if I run under azurerm version 2.71.0